# delay() line not allowing my Arduino code to run

Tags: arduino

The code is below

```
// initialize lights and sensors and valueHolders
int redN = 13;
int yellowN = 12;
int greenN = 11;
const int sensorN = A0;
int analogValueN = 0;

int redW = 10;
int yellowW = 9;
int greenW = 8;
const int sensorW = A1;
int analogValueW = 0;

int redS = 7;
int yellowS = 6;
int greenS = 5;
const int sensorS = A2;
int analogValueS = 0;

int redE = 4;
int yellowE = 3;
int greenE = 2;
const int sensorE = A3;
int analogValueE = 0;

//set thresholdValue;
const int threshValue = 200;

//initialize booleanSet for sectors
boolean bSet[] = {false, false, false, false};
void setBSet(){
  if(analogValueN > threshValue) bSet[0] = false;
  if(analogValueN < threshValue) bSet[0] = true;
  if(analogValueW > threshValue) bSet[1] = false;
  if(analogValueW < threshValue) bSet[1] = true;
  if(analogValueS > threshValue) bSet[2] = false;
  if(analogValueS < threshValue) bSet[2] = true;
  if(analogValueE > threshValue) bSet[3] = false;
  if(analogValueE < threshValue) bSet[3] = true;

//  if (analogValueN > threshValue){
//    bSet[0] = false;
//  } else {
//    bSet[0] = true;
//  }
}

//setup outputs
void start(){
   pinMode(redN, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(yellowN, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(greenN, OUTPUT);
   analogValueN = analogRead(sensorN);

   pinMode(redW, OUTPUT );
   pinMode(yellowW, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(greenW, OUTPUT);
   analogValueW = analogRead(sensorW);

   pinMode(redS, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(yellowS, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(greenS, OUTPUT);
   analogValueS = analogRead(sensorS);

   pinMode(redE, OUTPUT );
   pinMode(yellowE, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(greenE, OUTPUT);  
   analogValueE = analogRead(sensorE);
}

// set method for active sector
// ROS ==> red of sector
void active(int ROS){
  //set sector as go
  digitalWrite(ROS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ROS-1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ROS-2, HIGH);
  Serial.println('Pin' + (ROS-2) + "Active High");
}

//set method for light action
void action(int ROS){
  //set active for sector...
  active(ROS);
  //...and its complimentary sector
  if (ROS>8){
    active(ROS - 6);
  } else {
    active(ROS + 6);
  }
}

void runTraffic(){
  setBSet();
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    if (bSet[i]){
      action((3*i)+4);
//      delay(8000);
    }
  }
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  start();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  runTraffic();  
}
```

When i try to compile, it fails and error message is just "Error Compiling" and no reference to which line the error is coming from. But upon debugging i found the error to be in the delay line of the runTraffic() method. When i comment the line, the code compiles but it doesn't otherwise. But the delay works fine on other codes of mine.

What might be wrong with it?

[image: +Peto here is my prefrences window. No compile warning. What do I do now?]

Comment: what is your arduino IDE version?

Comment: Try setting "compiler warning: all" and let me know what is happened.

Comment: Pls where do i make that setting? `compiler warning: all` +Peto

Comment: Arduino IDE--> File--> Preferences --> Compiler warnings--> all

Comment: I added the preference window, as i didn't see the compile warning. Maybe that would help you understand my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lot of people have same problems with same IDE (probably that version is unstable).
I used the 1.6.4 to compile and no problem appear.

My advice is to unistall your Arduino IDE version (1.6.3) and install the 1.6.4 or something older and more stable.

[Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases#previous) you can download it and try which IDE works for you.

For now, i don't suggest the [1.6.5](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) (I've never tried it) but it could be a good candidate.